# What am I doing wrong in calculating quartiles?

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.array([1, 3, 7, 11])
print(np.quantile(x, 0.75))
print(np.quantile(x, 0.25))
```

```
8.0
2.5
```

How am I getting these as answers? What am I doing wrong? Am I being really dumb or is q1 and q3 9 and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is not reading the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html).  The default interpolation is `linear`; you seem to expect `midpoint`.

```
x = np.array([1, 3, 7, 11])
print(np.quantile(x, 0.75, interpolation="midpoint"))
print(np.quantile(x, 0.25, interpolation="midpoint"))
```

Output:

```
9.0
2.0
```

---

In your initial attempt, you used the default "linear" interpolation, which uses the fraction of the span represented by the two nearest points.  I've spent about an hour researching that fraction.  The NumPy documentation says:

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

The term `index` is not defined on this page, nor can I find it elsewhere in a few related methods.  The hypothesis I first posted in this answer is wrong -- now deleted.  I finally gave up, and tried to reverse-engineer the concept by computing the value of `index` as `(j - i) / fraction`:

```
print(f'{" q":3} {" val":4} {" i":3} {"j":3} {"frac"}  {"index"}')
x = np.array([0, 1, 3, 6, 10])
lo = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3,  6,  6, 10]
hi = [0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10]
for q in range(0, 11):
    interp = np.quantile(x, q/10)
    i, j = lo[q], hi[q]
    fraction = 0 if i == j else (interp - i) / (j - i)
    index    = 0 if i == j else (j - i) / fraction
    print(f'{round(q/10, 1):3} {round(interp, 1):4} {i:2} {j:2}   {round(fraction, 1):<3}  {round(index, 2):6.2f}')
```

Output:

```
 q   val  i  j   frac  index
0.0  0.0  0  0   0      0.00   # i == j
0.1  0.4  0  1   0.4    2.50
0.2  0.8  0  1   0.8    1.25
0.3  1.4  1  3   0.2   10.00
0.4  2.2  1  3   0.6    3.33
0.5  3.0  3  3   0      0.00   # i == j
0.6  4.2  3  6   0.4    7.50
0.7  5.4  3  6   0.8    3.75
0.8  6.8  6 10   0.2   20.00
0.9  8.4  6 10   0.6    6.67
1.0 10.0 10 10   0      0.00   # i == j
```

At this point, I am at a loss to explain the "fraction" concept.  I do understand that it's a statistical attempt to give a best estimate of the quantile value, assuming that more observations would be added to the collection `x`, coming from the same underlying (and unknown) distribution.

If anyone sees where my computations are wrong, or can illuminate this in any way, please edit this answer, comment, etc.  I'm about one long step out of my comprehension zone today.

Comment: Can you explain how you get the fraction? Also I see that 8 is 25% of the way from 7 to 11, but 2.5 is 75% of the way from 1 to 3.

Comment: I get the fraction by applying the formula given in the documentation.  Where are you not understanding that contextual definition of *fraction*?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what 'where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j' means.

Comment: Ah, ha!  I see now; I happen to understand it, but the ninnies didn't define the term on this page.  This will take a few minutes; I'll have to get to that after dinner.  In the meantime, you want `midpoint`, so I don't fear for your personal progress.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't fully understand what you did. I did however get an answer  on another site and thought I'd share it to see what you think. The zero-based index of where the first quartile should be is index = (n - 1) * q, or index = 0.75. For the third quartile, it would be 2.25. Fraction = index - int(index), so fraction = 0.25 for q3.

Answer (score 0):

The default interpolation mode of *np.quantile* is **linear**
(see the documentation).

You can get your expected result passing *interpolation='midpoint'*.